# Is it possible to switch from vm to dual boot without losing the files from vm?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox

I am currently using vm, but it's having performance issues. I know that dual booting linux would give me better performance, but I have a lot of necessary things installed in the vm that would be a pain to reinstall. Is there a way to switch to dual boot while keeping all of the programs and files?

Comment: Which virtualization software do you use?

Comment: I'm using virtualbox

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: Host OS is WIndows 10

Comment: Is Win10 installed in Legacy mode or UEFI mode?

Comment: It's installed in UEFI mode

Comment: Well that makes something that was going to be difficult to start with much, much harder.

Comment: So you would recommend I just reinstall everything over trying to that?